# Making some Bootstrap elements non-responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how can I make my bootstrap non-responsive? I'm having a problem with some of my div tags becoming responsive which messes up the overall look of the project.

My goal here is when I making my browser window smaller, the html and everything doesn't change in its looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a wrapper/container div around your inner html width a fixed width.

e.g.

```
<div class="site-container">

// Your html here

</div><!-- end site-container -->

.site-container {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```